# volatile vs not volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, shared-memory, memory-barriers

Let's consider the following piece of code in Java

```
int x = 0;
int who = 1
Thread #1:
   (1) x++;
   (2) who = 2;

Thread #2
   while(who == 1);
   x++;   
   print x; ( the value should be equal to 2 but, perhaps, it is not* )
```

(I don't know Java memory models- let assume that it is strong memory model- I mean: (1) and (2) will be doesn't swapped)
Java memory model guarantees that access/store to the 32 bit variables is atomic so our program is safe. But, nevertheless we should use a attribute `volatile` because *. The value of `x` may be equal to `1` because `x` can be kept in register when `Thread#2` read it. To resolve it we should make the `x` variable `volatile`. It is clear.

But, what about that situation:

```
    int x = 0;
    mutex m; ( just any mutex)
Thread #1:
       mutex.lock()
       x++;
       mutex.unlock()

    Thread #2
       mutex.lock()
       x++;   
       print x; // the value is always 2, why**?
       mutex.unlock()
```

The value of `x` is always `2` though we don't make it `volatile`. Do I correctly understand that locking/unlocking mutex is connected with inserting memory barriers?

Comment: Please post an MCVE.

Comment: What is a MCVE?

Comment: Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In the first snippet, HotSpot is allowed to optimize the loop to `while (true)` and it actually does perform such an optimization if you let it spin for awhile. I would call that code very unsafe.

Comment: ah, stackoverflow will not allow a comment containing a link to lmgtfy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to tackle this.  The Java memory model is kind of involved and hard to contain in a single StackOverflow post.  Please refer to Brian Goetz's *Java Concurrency in Practice* for the full story.

> The value of x is always 2 though we don't make it volatile. Do I correctly understand that locking/unlocking mutex is connected with inserting memory barriers?

First if you want to understand the Java memory model, it's always [Chapter 17 of the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) you want to read through.

That spec says:

> An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.

So yes, there's a memory visibility event at the unlock of your monitor.  (I assume by "mutex" you mean monitor.  Most of the locks and other classes in the `java.utils.concurrent` package also have *happens-before* semantics, check the documentation.)

*Happens-before* is what Java means when it guarantees not just that the events are ordered, but also that memory visibility is guaranteed.

```
We say that a read r of a variable v is allowed to observe a write w
to v if, in the happens-before partial order of the execution trace:

    r is not ordered before w (i.e., it is not the case that 
    hb(r, w)), and

    there is no intervening write w' to v (i.e. no write w' to v such
    that hb(w, w') and hb(w', r)).

Informally, a read r is allowed to see the result of a write w if there
is no happens-before ordering to prevent that read.
```

This is all from [17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5).  It's a little confusing to read through, but the info is all there if you do read through it.

Comment: @scottb Well he seemed to be asking about mutex/monitors.  The `volatile` was just part of his premise.  Sure we can often answer specific questions here, but understanding the full memory model is really needed to program well in Java.  For example, a lot of folks know what `volatile` does, but few seem to know what `final` does.  (Hint: read chapter 17 of the spec!!)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over some things. The following statement is true: Java memory model guarantees that access/store to the 32 bit variables is atomic. However, it does not follow that the first pseudoprogram you listed is safe. Simply because two statements are ordered syntactically does *not* mean that the visibility of their updates are also so ordered as viewed by other threads. Thread #2 may see the update caused by who=2 before the increment in x is visible. Making x volatile would still not make the program correct. Instead, making the variable 'who' voliatile would make the program correct. That is because volatile interacts with the java memory model in specific ways.

I feel like there is some notion of 'writing back to main memory' at the core of a common sense understanding of volatile which is incorrect. Volatile does not write back the value to main memory in Java. What reading from and writing to a volatile variable does is create what's called a happens-before relationship. When thread #1 writes to a volatile variable you're creating a relationship that ensures that any other threads #2 viewing that volatile variable will also be able to 'view' all the actions thread #1 has taken before that. In your example that means making 'who' volatile. By writing the value 2 to 'who' you are creating a happens-before relationship so that when thread #2 views who=2 it will similarly see an updated version of x.

In your second example (assuming you meant to have the 'who' variable too) the mutex unlocking creates a happens-before relationship as I specified above. Since that means other threads viewing the unlock of the mutex (ie. they are able to lock it themselves) they will see the updated version of x.

Comment: "As viewed by other threads" is key here.  Statements *within* a thread are guaranteed to be executed in program order (the order they appear in your code).  Visibility of memory writes *seen by other threads* is not guaranteed at all.  Mutex or `volatile` is required to make any statement at all about what thread 2 sees outside of "maybe."

Comment: Also "notion of 'writing back to main memory' ": yes.  Java is written for hardware that is not necessarily cache coherent.  Brian Goetz talks about this aspect of Java's design in *Java Concurrency in Practice* and says Java was designed for such CPUs.  It's a little weird but easy to get used to.  However, `volatile` expressly *does* create a "flush to main memory," that's what happens-before means (among some other things).

Comment: Functionally I'm not sure that 'flush to main memory' is the right way to phrase what happens. It's my understanding is that volatile is usually implemented as a memory barrier. These constructs don't necessarily cause CPU cache flushes; they simply limit how memory re-orderings can occur which influence how processors 'see' values.

Comment: As far as I know, most CPUs don't actually use memory barriers.  According to Intel (I asked their support), they have a separate bus, the QPI bus, that actually trades information on memory reads and writes, much faster than the main memory bus.  There's no actual memory write at all required on Intel architecture, and the caches are coherent (in most operations).

Comment: @markspace The JVM still has to write the value back from a register, whereas without a "memory barrier" it could decide to keep it in the register.

Comment: @biziclop Well we should define "memory barrier" then.  I assumed he meant a machine instruction like `mbar` or `sbar`.  If you mean some sort of logical barrier that tells the compiler to emit certain codes, then sure, a logical memory barrier is probably a fine way to think about it (but I'm no expert on javacc internals).

Comment: @markspace I'm not contradicting you, just appending to your comment. Hence why I put "memory barrier" in quotes, as I didn't mean it as a literal memory barrier instruction.

Comment: @biziclop  Yeah no worries.  I get contradicted all the time.  Other folks reading these comments might appreciate the extra explanations, so that's why I add them.